# The recent update to python now gives error messages for the import functions code - they still work and there are no errors in the modules,

Tags: python, updates

Since the most recent update to python I have a code file that runs a number of other functions in other code files that now shows errors.  When I import the files to the main file, the imports show up yellow and say they can't be imported, but the code files have no errors and when the file is run the imports work.

What do I need to do to fix this?

thanks.

### main code file example

```
import dates_paths
import est_checks

# ...

def main(cur_date, cur_text, cur_sufx, prev_wed, prev_sufx, last_pay, prev2_pay, fiscal_year, fy, fy_num, tmf_date, pcpath):

    est_checks.check_psa(cur_date, cur_text, cur_sufx, prev_wed, prev_sufx, last_pay, prev2_pay, fiscal_year, fy, fy_num, tmf_date, pcpath)

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cur_date, cur_text, cur_sufx, prev_wed, prev_sufx, last_pay, prev2_pay, fiscal_year, fy, fy_num, tmf_date, pcpath = hr_wed.get_dates_wed()
    main(cur_date, cur_text, cur_sufx, prev_wed, prev_sufx, last_pay, prev2_pay, fiscal_year, fy, fy_num, tmf_date, pcpath)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean you get import errors in the IDE but not on runtime. You probably need to use a different linter/rope.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.  forgive my ignorance...what do you mean by different linter/rope?

Comment: If you're using Visual Code, then the issue is just with it. You can solve it by having `__init__.py` file in every folder, and using imports by folder structure regardless of location. Example: If you have a folder called Folder1 inside it Folder2 and inside that `File.py` then you need to import using `Folder1.Folder2.File`.